# How to get Timezone in UTC format in ActionScript 3?

Tags: date, datetime, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I want to get the date and time in UTC format but whenever I am trying to get date that is giving me GMT format as follows (My System Time Zone is Pacific Time zone):

```
var dNow:Date = new Date();
trace(dNow); // Tue Feb 6 03:47:04 GMT-0800 2018
```

And I tried many ways to convert that to UTC format but unable to get the actual result.

So if anybody know how to convert from GMT to UTC format in Flex please help me to resolve this.

Comment: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#toUTCString()

Answer (score 0):

```
trace(dNow.getTime()/1000);
```

Flash works with milliseconds so dividing by 1000 will give the UTC time in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The Date object comes with a large number of UTC conversion functions built in. Have you tried them? https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html